# Can any one descride BingWM6.CAB used services in thire product?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

i Downloaded BingWM6.CAB from http://mobile.search.live.com/client/download_manual.aspx for bing maps showing in windows mobile.

I installed that application in windows mobile emulator its working fine but i need to know which services are using for accessing map controls and posing locations on map control?

I tried but i didn't found any information can one help me?

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the client in your application.  If you want to use Bing, you use [the Bing Maps Web Services SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980922.aspx).

Comment: Thank u for reply, what is that service? can i use for windows mobile?